# Does grant on *.* apply to databases created after the grant?

Tags: mysql, permissions

Suppose I have a few databases set up in MySQL.  I then issue

```
 grant select on *.* to 'backupman';
```

Later, I create a new database.

Does 'backupman' have select on the NEW database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it certainly does have `select` right on the new database.

When you use `*.*` it means you are [granting a global privilege](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html#grant-global-privileges).

> Global privileges are administrative or apply to all databases on a
>   given server. To assign global privileges, use ON *.* syntax (...)

Answer (score 0):

The `*.*` syntax is a global privilege in mysql. Global privileges apply to **all** databases on the server!